# How to avoid "tuple was already modified" error when using a BEFORE trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

In attempting to use triggers (PostgreSQL 9.1) to prevent duplicate entries, I receive the following error:

*ERROR:  tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command
HINT:  Consider using an AFTER trigger instead of a BEFORE trigger to propagate changes to other rows.emphasized text*

This error was received by executing:

```
update dx set cicd9='721.90', cdesc='osteoarthritis of spine, nos' where cicd9 = '721.90' and cdesc=' osteoarthritis of spine, nos';
```

(The attempt here is to remove the spaces in cdesc.)

If I "Return Null" from the update in the trigger, then everything gets deleted!?

How should the trigger be written to allow the calling "update dx" to work and yet prevent the result causing a duplicate key?

(Note: If the target record is being updated to a "new" value that already exists, I am trying to delete the "old" value and keep the "new" value. If I Return NULL on the update, then the old value is deleted, but there is no new value recorded??).

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the trigger I am working with:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dx_ins_up_before()
  RETURNS trigger AS 
  $func$

BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN

        RAISE NOTICE 'doing update';

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dx
                WHERE (cicd9,    cdesc,    groupid,    tposted)
                = (new.cicd9, new.cdesc, new.groupid, new.tposted) ) 
        THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'doing delete from update';

              DELETE FROM dx 
                WHERE (cicd9,    cdesc,    groupid,    tposted)
                = (OLD.cicd9, OLD.cdesc, OLD.groupid,  OLD.tposted ); 
        END IF;
        RETURN new; 
    ELSE
    -- doing insert
        RAISE NOTICE 'doing insert';

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dx
                WHERE (cicd9,    cdesc,    groupid,    tposted)
                = (new.cicd9, new.cdesc, new.groupid, new.tposted) ) 
        THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'return null from insert';
            RETURN NULL;    
        END IF;
    END IF;                 
END;    

$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


 CREATE TRIGGER dx_ins_up_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF cicd9,cdesc,groupid,tposted
ON dx
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dx_ins_up_before();
```

The constraint in dx is:

```
CONSTRAINT noduplicate_dx UNIQUE (cicd9, cdesc, groupid, tposted),
```

TIA

Comment: Don't issue an `UPDATE` from a `BEFORE` trigger. If you're modifying the current row, modify the `NEW` tuple.

Comment: You're confusing values and rows when using the "old" and "new" terminology. For the UPDATE  to "clean the path" for the new values to avoid violating the unique constraint, it should `delete from table where (col1,...)=(new.col1,...)`. Instead of that you're deleting the row that is being updated, which is not allowed.

Comment: I suggest you first do a bit of reading before using triggers to implement 2NF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form

Comment: @CraigRinger Where am I issuing an "Update" from within the trigger? Delete? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, DELETE. Note that in addition to the mistake Daniel pointed out, your approach won't work in the presence of concurrent UPDATEs.

Comment: If I understand, you try to DELETE a row to be updated if exists and then the UPDATE operation continues, that's imposible, because you try to update a deleted row. May be update the old row to default values should be enough instead of delete and insert sequence.

Comment: Great comments! They all help. Trying to compensate for poor table design is hard.